# Kubernetes -- how to remove terminated pods from being listed in Kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I have manually deleted a few Kubernetes pods via the Kubernetes UI dashboard. My problem is, the deleted pods are now being listed as "Terminated" on the Kubernetes Dashboard.  Typically, when a K8s resource gets deleted, it's automatically removed from being listed on the Dashboard.  Is there a kubectl command I should use to remove these pods from being listed as "Terminated"? They're cluttering up the dashboard.

Comment: Please provide details of your Kubernetes setup.

Comment: Seems like this pods are part of a deployment or statefullset. So you have to remove this superior resource.

Answer (score 2):

If you seeing the these pods status on the cli as terminated, then run the below command to delete the pods from there and then see on the dashboard, whether they disappears.

```
kubectl delete pod <pod_name> --force --grace-period=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, such should disappear after a few minutes.  Force-deleting a pod should only be done as a last resort.

Usually, if pods hanging around in Terminating state, there's some sort of clean-up going on in the background that is either slow or hung.  Try using "kubectl describe" or "kubectl logs" to gather more info about the state of your pods.